# Lowered accuracy when deploying a model to Docker

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am deploying a Machine Learning Model on Docker and I’ve run into some problems.
When I run the model locally and make predictions, the model gives predictions
with an accuracy of 0.8.

*Local example execution*
[image: Local example execution.]

But when I take the model to Docker, it has happened to me that the accuracy of
the predictions has gone from a 0.8 to a 0.3 approximately, despite being the
same model with the same weights.

*Docker execution example loading the weights with the Keras functions*
[image: Docker execution example loading the weights with the Keras functions.]

I tried to compress the weights and decompress them inside the container,
thinking it was a problem when copying the weights. But the result obtained was
the same, 0.3 accuracy.

I have also tried to train the model itself inside the Docker container, but the
results I have obtained have been the same. The accuracy in predictions was 0.3

In addition, I have tried to save the weights with Pickle, copy them in the
container and load them in the model. For some reason, this procedure has worked
for me and has given accuracy results of approximately 0.78.

*Docker execution example loading the weights with pickle*
[image: Docker execution example loading the weights with pickle.]

I am using Docker with the following versions: v20.10.13 and v20.10.14.

The Dockerfile file I’m using is as follows

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3

ENV APP_HOME /modelo_docker
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . $APP_HOME

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "embeddedtnet.py"]
```

And the versions of the libraries I’m using are as follows

```
uvicorn==0.17.6
fastapi==0.78.0
tensorflow==2.8.1
tensorflow-text==2.8.1
seaborn==0.11.2
scikit-learn==1.1.1
art==5.6
matplotlib==3.5.2
opencv-python==4.5.5.64
pandas==1.4.2
waitress==2.1.1
tensorflow-addons==0.17.0
pytesseract
nltk==3.7
requests==2.27.1
numpy==1.22.4
contractions==0.1.72
unidecode==1.3.4
protobuf~=3.19.0
```

These are the layers of the model:

```
class LSTMBLock(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, vocabulary):
    super(LSTMBLock, self).__init__()

    self.vectorization_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization(
        max_tokens=2000, standardize=None, output_mode='int', output_sequence_length=200, name='vectorization_layer')

    self.vectorization_layer.set_vocabulary(vocabulary)

    self.from_ragged_to_dense = tf_text.keras.layers.ToDense(
        pad_value=0, mask=True)

    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
        input_dim=len(vocabulary), output_dim=200, mask_zero=True)

    self.maxpooling = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3)

    self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(
        filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu')

    self.spadrop = tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout1D(0.25)

    self.bidirectionalLSTM = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='sigmoid',recurrent_dropout=0, dropout=0.25, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', return_sequences=True),
                                                           merge_mode='concat', name="bidirectional")

    self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(
        filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu')

    self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()

def call(self, inputs: List[str]) -> tf.Tensor:

    x = self.vectorization_layer(inputs)
    x = self.from_ragged_to_dense(x)
    x = self.embedding(x)
    x = self.maxpooling(x)
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.spadrop(x)
    x = self.bidirectionalLSTM(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)

    return x
```

So far, I haven’t found the reason why this is happening and neither why it has worked with Pickle.